# Error when forecasting volatility with GARCH model in R

Tags: r, garch, finance, error-message, volatility

I am trying to forecast volatility on four different time series which is returns of SP500, Nasdaq 100, Dow Jones and Russel 2000. the four time series consists of 3259 observation and is divided into 45% training and 55% forecasting analysis. the coding looks like this for Russel 2000:

```r
insample_ts4 <- my_ts4russel[1:1465]

spec100 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                    mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 0), include.mean = TRUE),
                    distribution.model = "sstd")

model100 <- ugarchfit(spec100, insample_ts4, solver = "hybrid")

print(model100)

forcast1 <- rep(0,1794)

for (i in 1:1794) {
  ystar_exp <- my_ts4russel[1:(1464+i)]
  forecast_model1 <- ugarchfit(spec100, ystar_exp, solver = "hybrid")
  for_obj <- ugarchforecast(forecast_model1, n.ahead = 1)
  forcast1[i] <- for_obj@forecast$sigmaFor[1]
}

print(forcast1)
```

However I get an optimization error when trying to forecast the volatility on SP500 and Russel 2000. it works fine on Nasdaq 100 and Dow Jones. the error when forecasting the volatility on SP500 and Russel 2000 is that it cannot forecast all 1794 periods it suddenly stops and gives me this error:

```r
> Error in robustvcv(fun= f, pars = ipars[estidx,1] nlag = nlag, he's =fit$hessian: object 'b' was not found
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Perhaps R SIG FInance mailing list might be a better place to get help on this kind of question. I posted something there fairly recently, and Alexios Ghalanos (the author of `rugarch`) responded very quickly, I think within a day. You could also try doing some homework first: find the R code of the `rugarch` package, search for the specific error message in it and see under what circumstances it is generated.

Comment: In general, that kind of problem occur when there is not convergence. Try to look at the results you get for the value of *i* it works. You will surely see that the forecasting is too big or too small. To correct that, you can either verify you data (remove outliers, remove zero, etc..) or change the starting point of the optimization.